# how solve this second-order nonlinear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

how solve this second-order nonlinear equation

[image]

my work 
I know that we first convert differential X'' to D^2 and try to get the general solution so

suppose  D^2 =  X''

then

D^2 + (delta)*D+x(x^2-x) =0

i'm stuck in this step , I need just first push to solve the wholly equation

thanks

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form solution at all.

Comment: what should I do now ? , I need to solve this equation

Comment: Are you sure the question wants a closed form solution? Perhaps instead they want some kind of perturbative expansion or qualitative analysis.

Comment: yes, it just want to write the equation as system of two first-order

Comment: you can try a numerical solution

Comment: You only want to write it as a system of two first order equations? That's easy, define $v=x'$, then replace $x'$ with $v$ and $x''$ with $v'$. Then if you like you can rearrange the equations to read $x'=v,v'=\dots$.

Comment: yes , I need only that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation

$x'' + \delta x' -x + x^3 = \gamma \cos \omega t \tag 1$

is an example of [Duffing's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation).  No closed form solution is known, and I doubt it has one in terms of elementary functions.  The solutions exhibit many important and engaging phenomena, ranging from bounded oscillation to chaos, depending on the parameter values.  Check out the linked citing; it's worth reading.

Meanwhile, if what is wanted here is to simply cast (1) into  first-order form, we can exploit the standard procedure of setting

$v = x', \tag 2$

so that

$v' = x'', \tag 3$

and then (1) may be written

$v' + \delta v - x + x^3 = \gamma \cos \omega t, \tag 4$

or

$v' = - \delta v + x - x^3 + \gamma \cos \omega t, \tag 5$

which together with (2) forms the first order system

$x' = v, \tag 6$

$v' = - \delta v + x - x^3 + \gamma \cos \omega t \tag 7$

in the two variables $x$ and $v$.